# Having XML Validation / namespace issues using the IBM Processor for XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm receiving the following XML message from a third party vendor.  I have no control over the incoming message.  I've pared it down to it's simplest form while still producing the error.  The XML message:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body/>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The xsl file I am using is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:import-schema
        namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        schema-location="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>Help</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I try to run the transformation within Eclipse using the IBM processor for XSLT 2.0 with the "Enable Validation" box checked, I get the following error during xml validation:

```
cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'soap:Envelope'
```

Is there any way to make this pass validation even though I have no control over the incoming message?  If I did have control over the incoming message I'd do this and it'd work wonderfully:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
                            http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body/>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: I don't have the IBM's XSLT 2.0 processor, but **the provided transformation is performed OK with these three XSLT 2.0 processors: Saxon 4.6EE, AltovaXML, XQSharp (XmlPrime).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the details of the IBM XSLT 2.0 processor, but it seems clear from the symptoms that the validation phase on the source document doesn't have access to the schema declared using xsl:import-schema in the stylesheet; you will have to look in the documentation for some other way of telling the validation process where to find a suitable schema.